# How can I make some text invisible (show in label) in iPhone application using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make some text invisible which is displayed in a label.  I can make it invisible using this:

```
labelname.visible = NO;
```

But this creates a problem when I call a different screen.  I need a different way for to make label text invisible that does not create this type of problem.

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're having with visible=NO?  What do you mean by "when I call different screen"?

Comment: And what class is leble?

Comment: I am doing my project using in cocos2d.Where i use Scene or layer interface like:
@interface GameScene : Scene {}
@end
@interface GameLayer :  Layer{
@end

If i use visible=NO then i can not call this GameScene from different scene like LandingScene.When call the program is going gdb

Answer (score 0):

You could add/remove the label from the layer to hide/show it, just retain the label instance for later retrieval.  Although, [yourLabel setVisible:NO] should not cause problems between scenes.